# Question marks instead of citations, bibliography not showing up

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've browsed topics allready here but nothing really helped. I'm building it through: pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex, but it's still the same.

bibliografia.bib

```
@BOOK{Nodzynski,
AUTHOR = {Nodzyński M., Warszycki T.},
TITLE =  {Verilog HDL Podręcznik języka dla projektantów układów cyfrowych},
YEAR =   {Praca dyplomowa PW, Warszawa 2003}
}
```

ending of document.tex

```
\newpage
\bibliography{bibliografia}
```

fragment of content

```
\cite{Nodzynski}
```

I think problem is in my package preamble, bad order or sth like that.

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{hypernat}

\usepackage{extsizes}         
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[hide]{todo}                    
\usepackage[basic,physics]{circ}          
\usepackage[sf,bf,outermarks]{titlesec}     
\usepackage{tocloft}                        
\usepackage{expdlist}  
\usepackage{flafter}     
\usepackage{array}      
\usepackage{listings}    

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,     
  breakatwhitespace=false,    
  breaklines=true,               
  captionpos=b,                  
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    
  deletekeywords={...},       
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
  extendedchars=true,          
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,                 
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
  language=Verilog,                 
  morekeywords={*,...},          
  numbers=left,                  
  numbersep=5pt,                
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, 
  rulecolor=\color{black},       
  showspaces=false,             
  showstringspaces=false,     
  showtabs=false,               
  stepnumber=2,                 
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     
  tabsize=2,                   
  title=\lstname        
}

\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=period,labelfont={bf,small},textfont=small]{caption}  
\usepackage{appendix}    
\usepackage{floatflt}   
\usepackage{here}     
\usepackage{makeidx}     
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like  [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't put any bibliography style. Compiling with bibtex it says:

`I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file`

Try with this:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
```

You may use the style that best suites you.

By the way, the required fields for the book entry are author/editor, title, publisher and year. You are missing some of them.